# Using React Native to run JavaScript code from an existing native app without having to display a component

Tags: react-native

The official documentation for React Native explains how to add React Native views to existing native applications. However, it does not explain how to run React Native code written in JavaScript from a native application, without having to display any React Native component. Does the framework provide a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think reason being, R-N works on top of Native components and not other way round. I have not come across anything that you are looking.

Comment: I might be incorrect though. I would be interesting to see if iOS and Android has a support for embedding R-N js components in future. 

https://www.raywenderlich.com/124075/javascriptcore-tutorial

^ Something i found.

Comment: This is not using R-N